# Is "necesse" an adjective or an adverb

Tags: vocabulary, syntax, meaning, adjective, adverb

## Introduction

My enquiry arrises from a passage in “Lingua Latina Per Se Illustrata: Familia Romana” in its tenth chapter which is entitled “BESTIAE ET HOMINES” on its fifty-ninth line which is as follows.

> "Spīrāre necesse est hominī."

The definitions of form I found are given below.

### Dictionary Entries

1. A Latin Dictionary, 1962
   p. 1195, Adj.
2. Pocket Oxford Latin Dictionary, 2005
   p. 120, Adv.
3. Oxford Latin Dictionary, 2012
   vol. 2, p. 128, Adv.
4. Chambers Murray Latin-English Dictionary, 2016
   p. 457, Adj.

### Android Applications

1. Collins Latin Dictionary
   Adj.
2. Whitakers Words
   Adj.

## Enquiry

Can anyone provide a reasoned parsing of "Spīrāre necesse est hominī." which may be lent to a sense of whether "necesse" is likely to be an adjective or an adverb?

Answer (score 11):

Lewis & Short, Gaffiot, Georges and Forcellini agree that it is an adjective. Oxford appears to be alone with its opinion that it is an adverb, and I wonder if the entry itself has anything to say about that. *Aliquid alicui necesse est* is a very common expression, and as Draconis has explained, a neuter adjective hardly seems out of place here.

But *necesse* is a very unusual adjective indeed. It is highly defective, i.e., most forms are never used; in fact, in classical Latin, *necesse* is the *only* existing form. It exists only in the neuter gender, and is only used in connection with the verbs *esse* and *habere*. (And even the latter is not all that common, I think.) It cannot be used attributively, i.e., you cannot say *medicamen necesse accipio* etc.

Therefore it is not particularly helpful to think of *necesse* as an adjective, because you cannot do most of the things with it that you could do with an adjective. Think of *necesse esse* as a fixed expression.

By the way, haud necesse est in figura *necesse est* in linguam Anglicam transferenda verbum "necessary" adhibere. "Must" aut "needs to" etc. satis est.

Answer (score 7):

> Spīrā-re necesse est homin-ī
> breathe-INF necessary be.3SG.PRES human-DAT.SG
> *Breathing is necessary for a human.*

I would call it an **adjective** without a qualm. It's linked to a nominal (an infinitive verb) by a copula, and that's a syntactic context that adjectives appear in:

> Errā-re humān-um est
> err-INF human-N.SG.NOM be.3SG.PRES
> *To err is human.*

> *Errā-re humān-ē est
> err-INF human-ADV be.3SG.PRES
> **To err is humanly.*

*Multē*, *magnopere*, etc are also ungrammatical in that context.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think it's productive to attempt to determine the part of speech of this word - it's neither, since it modifies neither a noun nor a verb. **necesse/necessum est, opus est, ūsus est** and **oportet** are all *predicative expressions* that are semantically indivisible, forming the predicate together. If you classify **necesse** as an adjective, you'd have to classify **opus, ūsus** as adjectives—afaik using ***magnum** opus est* to mean this is impossible, it will mean "the task is big", so you have to say ***valdē** opus est*— ...and then perhaps analyse **oportet** and the rest of Latin verbs as containing a head - the ending - stuck to an adjectival base (hey, there are plenty of languages where adjectives = verbs!). At least in my ignorance of generative syntax I don't see what would stop you. In short, here seems to be where traditional grammar becomes useless.

Pinkster's 2015 Oxford Latin Syntax Vol. 1 p. 622 suggests that these govern imperative argument clauses aka 'final' clauses since they regularly lack the subordinator **ut** (*necesse est faciās ~ volō faciās*), apparently with only a single instance of **nē** (surprising!).