# Why is accusative pronoun "te" used in this construction?

Tags: grammar-choice, lingua-latina-per-se-illustrata, accusative, dative, accusativus-cum-infinitivo

In lines 137-138 of chapter XIII of *Lingua latina per se illustrata. Familia Romana* one can read:

> Iam necesse est tē dormire.

I don't understand why the accusative pronoun *tē* is used in the above sentence, since I've always seen the construction *necesse est* used with dative. One can find an example in [this post](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/17026/):

> Spīrāre necesse est hominī,

where *hominī* is in dative case. Another example from the same book:

> Mihi necesse nōn est scrībere posse

where we find the dative personal pronoun *mihi*.

In [this question](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/16256/), I've find similar constructions with accusative pronouns. But I don't understand when do I have to use dative or accusative. Can anyone explain it?

Comment: How do you know it is the accusative and not the ablative?

Comment: @FlatAssembler It's not like the ablative would be any easier to make sense of – quite to the contrary …

Answer (score 11, accepted):

These two sentences involve different analyses, which can be shown by using the following test: replacement of the infinitive (clause) by the neuter pronoun *hoc*. In the first example the infinitival clause *te dormire* can be replaced by *hoc*, whereas in the second example it is only the infinitive *spirare* that can be replaced by this neuter pronoun.

*Iam necesse est hoc* (i.e. *te dormire*)

*Hoc* (i.e. *spirare*) *necesse est homini*.

So notice that in the first sentence the accusative pronoun *te* is an argument of *dormire* (*te* is the subject of this infinitive), whereas in the second one the dative noun *homini* is an argument of *necesse est* (*homini* is the indirect object of *necesse est*).

---

EDIT (motivated by the comments below):

I agree with gaufridus when saying:

> Recast with a gerund, the sentences seem more obviously distinct: *necesse est te dormire* 'your sleeping is necessary' and *necesse est tibi dormire* 'sleeping is necessary for you' (even if the sense is somewhat changed, it makes the difference more obvious to an Anglophone).

Concerning the English translation of an Acc. cum Inf. construction like *Necesse est te dormire* as 'It is necessary for you to sleep', it is worth noting that some scholars have claimed that the assignment of the accusative case *te* in this Latin example is carried out by a null (prepositional-like?) complementizer similar to "for" in English constructions like ***For** him to invite Mary would be stupid* (please see page 25 of their paper downloadable at this [link](https://www.academia.edu/3199346/Consequences_of_the_Analysis_of_Latin_infinitival_Clauses_for_the_Theory_of_Case_and_Control)). Following gaufridus's relevant parallelism, cf. the latter sentence with *His inviting Mary would be stupid*.

It is then important to point out that in Latin the accusative case of the subject of the infinitive is *not* necessarily assigned by the main verb. E.g. see the discussion in this [**link**](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/16256/accusative-case-marking-of-subjects-in-infinitival-clauses) concerning how the accusative case can be assigned in examples like *Video te (dormire)*, *Dico te dormire*, and *Necesse est te dormire*. In particular, the discussion of the last example (where the main verb is *not* transitive) is mainly relevant for Charo's question.

As for tony's comment, it is important to realize that *Iam necesse est **te** dormire* and *Iam necesse est **tibi** dormire* involve different analyses: cf. above *Iam hoc necesse est* (*hoc* = *te dormire*) and *Iam hoc necesse est tibi* (*hoc* = *dormire*). As noted, the dative *tibi* is not the subject of the infinitive *dormire* but the indirect object of *necesse est*.
Still, one (e.g. tony) can wonder why it is then the case that the sentence with the dative can have a translation that is similar to the one with the 'Accusativus cum Infinitivo'. The answer is that the dative (e.g. *tibi* above) is [coreferent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coreference) with the null subject of the infinitive: i.e. the "dative of interest" *tibi*, which grammatically depends on *necesse est*, is coreferent with the implicit agent of the infinitive *dormire*. Technically speaking, *tibi* is said to be the [controller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_(linguistics)) of the null/[PRO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PRO_(linguistics)) subject of the infinitive.

---

Let me conclude this discussion with a comparison of the two following examples, which are very often treated as synonymous in many Latin grammars:

*Iam necesse est tibi dormire*.

*Iam tibi est dormiendum*.

One could say: "you, Mitomino, have just told us that in the former example *tibi* is not the agent of *dormire*. Assuming that both examples are synonymous, should/could one then conclude that *tibi* is not really an agent (cf. the traditional term ["dative of agent"](https://dcc.dickinson.edu/grammar/latin/dative-agent)) either in the latter sentence?"

Short answer: Yes, that's right! Despite appearances (and despite what grammatical tradition has told us), *tibi* is NOT the grammatical agent in *Iam tibi est dormiendum*. Those of you who are interested in knowing why *tibi* has not been grammatically construed as an agent in this construction, take a look at the two following references [NB: these two texts are quite readable since their authors don't use a technical vocabulary].

Suárez Martínez, P. M. (2001). "Le datif d’agent (*datiuus auctoris*). Un fantôme dans la syntaxe latine." In C. Moussy (Ed.). *De Lingua Latina Novae Quaestiones*. Actes du Xè Colloque International de Linguistique Latine (pp. 597-607). Louvain/Paris/Sterling,Virginia: Peeters. Downloadable at https://www.unioviedo.es/pmsuarez/Articulos_files/Le%20datif%20agent.pdf

Danesi, S., C. Johnson & J. Barðdal. (2017). "Between the Historical Languages and the Reconstructed Language: An Alternative Approach to the Gerundive + “Dative of Agent” Construction in Indo-European." *Indogermanische Forschungen* 122 (1): 143–188.
Downloadable at https://www.researchgate.net/publication/320958533_Between_the_Historical_Languages_and_the_Reconstructed_Language_An_Alternative_Approach_to_the_Gerundive_Dative_of_Agent_Construction_in_Indo-European

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about *te dormire* with the accusative *te* as an object of the verb? Looking in a few online dictionaries, the senses they give of the verb *dormire* are all intransitive, and I couldn't find examples of the verb used in a transitive or reflexive way. Like the OP, I would not have thought of this as a possible parsing.

Comment: @JamesMartin  Note that _te_ is not the object of _dormire_ but its subject (NB: in Latin subjects of infinitival clauses are often marked with the accusative case). Note also that _te dormire_ is not the direct object but the subject of _necesse est_. For related discussion, see my previous question (please take a look at the last link provided by the OP): https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/16256/accusative-case-marking-of-subjects-in-infinitival-clauses?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: I agree with @JamesMartin that it would be a good idea to add the contents of your comment to the answer. Would you please do it?

Comment: @Mitomino: What if it had been written: "iam necesse est tibi dormire" = "now it is necessary for you to sleep"?  Here's one from Cicero, "de Senectute 30): "nihil necesse est mihi de me ipso dicere," = "it is not necessary for me to say anything concerning myself,". Given the inclusion of both "mihi" & "me", why did Cicero feel the need to include the intensifier, "ipso"?

Comment: @Mitomino thanks, that's illuminating. That does sound like it belongs in the answer to the question of why *te* is in the accusative case in this sentence (although indeed, thanks, now I see that the OP was definitely aware of more than I was). What is a good reference to learn more about these accusative + infinitive constructions?

Comment: @JamesMartin In the following link you'll find some relevant references that contain an _introductory_ discussion of the accusative marking of the subject of infinitival clauses: https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/11201/please-recommend-reference-grammar-for-someone-with-an-undergraduate-degree-in-l  For some _more advanced_ textbooks, see the comment of my answer in the previous post (e.g. take a look at Pinkster's _The Oxford Latin Syntax_, published by Oxford University Press).

Comment: This is a really good answer. A lot of the trickiness here is in English marking the subject of an infinitive with the preposition *for,* so that both *te* and *tibi* look the same in translation. Recast with a gerund, the sentences seem more obviously distinct: *necesse est te dormire* 'your sleeping is necessary' and *necesse est tibi dormire* 'sleeping is necessary for you' (even if the sense is somewhat changed, it makes the difference more obvious to an Anglophone).

Comment: @gaufridus  Yes, I agree with you. Concerning the English translation of an Acc. cum Inf. construction like _Necesse est te dormire_ as 'It is necessary for you to sleep', it is worth noting that some scholars have claimed that the assignment of the accusative case _te_ in this sentence is carried out by a null (prepositional-like?) complementizer similar to "for" in English constructions like _**For** him to invite Mary would be stupid_: see page 25 of their paper https://www.academia.edu/3199346/Consequences_of_the_Analysis_of_Latin_infinitival_Clauses_for_the_Theory_of_Case_and_Control

Comment: @Mitomino Interesting, that fits well with my own less formal analysis.

Comment: @gaufridus  I've just incorporated your relevant comment on English gerunds in my EDIT above. I'm not a native speaker of English but my intuition is that your interesting parallelism with gerunds also holds for the following pair: cf. _For him to invite Mary would be stupid_ & _His inviting Mary would be stupid_.

Comment: @Charo: Please share your thoughts on Mitomino's answer.

Comment: @tony:  Now I found it much more complete: in my opinion, it's an excellent answer. Maybe it would be worth asking a new question about the usages of the *accusativus cum infinito*: in other sources, I have only seen such construction associated to indirect speech.