# What is the role of "ipso" in this quote from Cicero?

Tags: classical-latin, latin-to-english-translation, pronouns, cicero

Following on from Q: [Why is accusative pronoun "te" used in this construction?](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/21614/1982), in this quote from Cicero:

> "nihil necesse est mihi de me ipso dicere, quamquam est id quidem senile aetatique nostrae conceditur." (de Senectute 30),

it is clear that Cicero is talking about himself:

> "I need say nothing of myself in this connexion, though to do so is an old-man's privilege and permitted  to one of my age.".

Therefore, why deploy the intensifier, *ipso*, the ablative of *ipse* = "self"?

Comment: You used more words to ask your question than strictly logically necessary. Why did you do that?

Comment: I think you mean, "Why did you, yourself, do that?".

Comment: @Joonas llmavirta: Most of the words, here, are Cicero's and the translation: I accept that, "in this connexion" could be deleted.

Comment: @Adam: Most amusing!

Comment: @tony You miss my point. Cicero doesn't use the bare minimum to convey his message, and neither do you. Language is not a logic puzzle to be solved but a tool to be used. I just got the feeling that some of this question comes from an unjustified premise of minimality.

Comment: @Joonas llmavirta: I see. Cicero had already used "mihi" & "me"; I just wondered how the "ipso" came into it--it could've been a point of which I was unaware. Therefore, do you believe that Cicero was simply being verbose--over-egging the pudding?

Comment: What is the context for the quote? It is possible that Cicero wanted to really emphasize that it was he, himself.

Comment: @Adam: Hadn't he already done that: "mihi" & "me"? Your joke, above, includes a valid point: would you say, "Me, myself & I are going for a walk."? Why did Cicero?

Comment: This is not Cicero, its the elder Cato, a very different and difficult character.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A couple of miscellaneous points, some iterated from my comments:

1. You used more words to ask your question than strictly logically necessary.
   Why did you do that?
   Cicero doesn't use the bare minimum to convey his message, and neither do you.
   No one does.

   Try not to treat language as a logic puzzle to be solved but as a tool to be used.
   You seem to start from a premise that expression should be minimal, but that is rarely what languages use is optimised for.
   Try to let go of that premise.
2. There was a choice to be made in constructing that sentence, and Cicero might not have meant anything by the choice he made.
   This instance of word choice sounds so mundane to me that it'd move on.

   If there's context that makes the question more meaningful, that changes the matter.
   I don't see such context here.
3. Be careful with the symbol "=", both in writing and in thinking.
   It is not true that *ipse* = "self".
   That word can also end up being translated as "very", "exactly", "right", or not at all.
   Equating two words is easily misleading.
   Latin and English pronouns work differently.

   The translation of your Cicero passage could well be exactly the same with or without the *ipso*.
   Translation is about understanding the meaning in Latin and expressing it in English, not about mapping words to words.

   If you want to express a correspondence between two words, you could use the symbol "≈" instead, produced e.g. by typing `&approx;`.
4. Perhaps the word *ipso* underlines reflexivity.
   Saying *me ipso* instead of *me* reminds the audience that the same guy is both the subject and the object.
   Redundancy like that is very common and very useful.
5. Perhaps the inclusion of the pronoun is idiomatic.
   At least to me it sounds more natural with it than without.

Answer (score 0):

If you scan the text for ipse, ipso, ipsa, you see, that Ciceros Cato regularly uses a indication with an emphazising ipse. This is a regular rhetoric element.

[Cicero: Cato Major de Senectute](https://www.gottwein.de/Lat/CicSen/sen01la.php)